# PHP variable with Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I want to write PHP code that check few conditions and then trigger JavaScript on the loaded page.

The php file is:

```
$jwplayer= "<script>jwplayer('video1').setup({playlist:$file});</script>";
$url2= "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/index.php";
$url3= "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/index3.php";
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
if($url2==$url) {
  $file= "/media/video.xml";
  echo $jwplayer;
}
 if($url3==$url) {
  $file= "/media/video2.xml";
  echo $jwplayer;
}
```

I'm using PHP include to include the above code.

If the URL of the page is equal to the value of `$url2` above, then I want the playlist updated. This would be done by setting `$file` to "/media/video.xml" and executing the required JavaScript I am attempting to include.

Comment: Your question makes no sense to me. What do you mean by "I want that $file will change it the "playlist:" JavaScript code"?

Comment: This code will lead to a fatal error. What is the real code and what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Shouldn't the double quotes around the video1 be single quotes - `jwplayer('video1')`

Comment: I corrected the syntax errors below in my answer.

Comment: this is not the real code, because it too long.

Comment: If you can't list the code describe your error/bad result better.

Comment: Be careful about the two variables that are directly up against each other $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]. I don't think this will give you the result you want. Several people separated these in the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$file= "/media/default.xml";

$url = "http://" . $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
$url2= "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/index.php";

if($url2==$url) {
    $file= "/media/video.xml";
}

$jwplayer= "<script>jwplayer(\"video1\").setup({playlist:".$file."});</script>";
echo $jwplayer;
```

Comment: did you also missed to escape double quotas around video1?

Comment: If you get that error its possible the nested variable is not working. I have updated my code.

Comment: now it works.
what I want is to set many if(url=urlx)
and the $jwplayer stay outside the "if"

Comment: You want a default value for jwplayer, and for it to echo every case? I updated again

Comment: sorry, but no.
I want to change only the playlist item. i don't want to write $jwplayer in each condition. thanks for your help. I'd update my first post

Answer (score 1):

I would start with fixing your syntax errors and go from there:

```
function jwPlayer($xml) {
    echo("<script>jwplayer('video1').setup({playlist:'$xml'});</script>");
}
$url2= "http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . "/index.php";
$url = "http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
if($url2 == $url) {
    $file= "/media/video.xml";
    jwPlayer($file);
} else {
    jwPlayer("path/to/other/file.xml");
}
```

Defining a variable after its use will do nothing but cause you problems.

Comment: I want the $jwplayer will be constant, just the $file change, according to the condition

Comment: @user1389940 look at my updated answer; put the output into a `function` and call it however you like.

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this

```
$file = "somefile.xml";
$url2= "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/index.php";
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; 
if($url2==$url) 
    $file= "/media/video.xml";
$jwplayer= "<script>jwplayer(\"video1\").setup({playlist:$file});</script>";
echo $jwplayer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$url2= "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/index.php";
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

if($url2==$url) {
  $file= "/media/video.xml";
  echo $jwplayer= "<script>jwplayer("video1").setup({playlist:$file});</script>";
}
```

in you code it looks like your trying to get the value of $file by echo'ing the script..

hope that helps

Comment: I want the variable jwplayer ($jwplayer) will be constant. just $file would change, according to conditions... I've my first post.

Answer (score 0):

There is a few mistakes within this code.

In the moment you assign this string, the variable `$file` is undefined, you have to define it first.

```
$jwplayer= "<script>jwplayer('video1').setup({playlist:$file});</script>"
```

On a javascript object literal, you must have to quote a string. If you don't the content of the variable `$file` will become a undefined javascript variable.

```
{playlist:"$file"} //playlist is a string
```

Try this

```
$url2 = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/index.php";
$url = "http://" . $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
if($url2==$url) {
    $file= "/media/video.xml";
    $jwplayer= "<script>jwplayer('video1').setup({playlist:'$file'});</script>";
    echo $jwplayer;
}
```

I'm not sure what do you mean by "constant", but I would do something like this, but I can't tell for sure if this works just with the little information provided in the actual question.

```
<?php
    $url2 = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/index.php";
    $url = "http://" . $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
    $file = "";
    if($url2==$url) {
        $file = "/media/video.xml";
    }
?>

<script>
jwplayer('video1').setup({playlist:'<?=$file>'});
</script>
```